# how can i use a Boolean in a media query?

Tags: media-queries

for example:
   @media only screen and (<%=b%>) and (orientation: portrait)
where b is a Boolean defined previously in the page.
the above does not work for me...

thanks!

Comment: That's not how media queries work... (how is `b` even defined in the page anyway?)

Comment: <% boolean b = true; %>

Comment: Is that JSP or something?

Comment: The second part of the media query has to be an expression. Is b a variable which holds a media expression? Can you tell us the possible values your expression can hold?